# PHP based MySQL database managers

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm looking to some lightweight open source php based MySQL database managing script.

I would essentially prefer something that is packed into a single file, and has a decent UI and features.

PS: I already know about PHPMiniAdmin, I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLBuddy is pretty nice: http://www.sqlbuddy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need [PHP-Mini-Admin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/)

> It is a light-weight alternative to
>   phpmyadmin

[Source](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin is still my favourite

http://www.phpmyadmin.net

C.